# What is the probability of getting three sixes in a row?

Tags: probability

A fair die is rolled $n$ times. Find the probability of getting three sixes in a row.

Now, I have seen some solutions to this problem that involve linear homogeneous recursions (used to count the $N$ tuples that have no three consecutive sixes), however, I find that this approach is too complicated for what seems like a simple problem in basic probability. 

I tried solving this with combinatorics, using a binomial distribution, and counting the sixes as Wins and all other numbers as losses and then calculating the probability of $r$ winning streaks but all my attempts failed. I was wondering if there are some elementary (i.e. involving techniques learned in introductory courses to probability) solutions, or if the recursion method is the simplest we have.

Comment: Can it be $(n-2)(\frac {1}{6})^3 (\frac {5}{6})^{n-3}$ for $n\geq 3$?

Comment: @rohan can you elaborate?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for $n=3$.

Comment: *Exactly* three 6's in a row *once*, or what ??

Comment: @trueblueanil at least three sixes in a row at least once

Comment: @Rohan: No, that's just some expression which kinda looks similar to the probability of getting $3$ sixes, which hapens to be $\binom{n}{3}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{3}\cdot\left(\frac56\right)^{n-3}$. However, here we are asked for the probability of $3$ **consecutive** sixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binomial probabilities $(\frac16\;$and$\;\frac56)$ *are* involved, but I'm afraid you'll need recursion, too.

Let $q_n$ be the Pr that there is **not** a streak of three $6's$ in $n$ trials.

Denoting the last few results, $N$ denoting a non-$6$, they could be

$...N$ preceded by $q_{n-1}$, or
$...N6$ preceded by $q_{n-2}$, or
$...N66$ preceded by $q_{n-3}$. That's all !

Thus $q_n = (\frac56)q_{n-1} + (\frac5{36})q_{n-2} + (\frac5{216})q_{n-3}$

with starting values being $q_1=1, q_2 = 1, q_3 = \frac{215}{216}$

Finally, $p_n = 1 - q_n$